# Python age verification

Tags: python, datetime, verification

On my join script you have to be 13+ to join. The problem is when I check it against certain dates it only works if I do it a month back.

```
    cur_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(days=4848.12)
    time_13 = str(cur_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    bmonth = self.get_argument('bmonth', '')
    bday = self.get_argument('bday', '')
    byear = self.get_argument('byear', '')
    birthday = byear + '-' + bmonth + '-' + bday
    if time_13 <= birthday:
        c_age = True
    else:
        c_age = ''
    if c_age:
        response = tornado.escape.json_encode({"error":"true","msg":"You must be 13 years of age or older to join uSocial'N"})
```

Comment: Give some examples of "certain dates".

Comment: Also [13 years in days](http://www.google.com/search?q=13+years+in+days) is 4748 days rather than 4848.

Comment: Well I am comparing it against the date 13 years ago from the day it is currently. If I enter today's date 13 years ago it comes up false, but if I go back to Oct 31 13 years ago it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to compare dates and date ranges rather than strings.

Assuming you get strings for birthday parts:

```
bmonth = self.get_argument('bmonth', '')
bday = self.get_argument('bday', '')
byear = self.get_argument('byear', '')

bd = datetime.datetime(int(byear), int(bmonth), int(bday))
min_age = datetime.timedelta(weeks = 52*13)
if datetime.datetime.now() - bd < min_age:
    response = tornado.escape.json_encode({"error":"true", "msg":
                     "You must be 13 years of age or older to join uSocial'N"})
```

Comment: This brings out the same result.

Comment: Ok so I got it by doing `bd = datetime.datetime(int(byear), int(bmonth), int(bday))        min_age = datetime.timedelta(days=4748.12)          if datetime.datetime.now() - bd <= min_age:`

Comment: Congrats @egor83. I'm switching from php to python for my backend sync so helped a bunch with that one.